# The type ConsistencyLevel exists in both Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client and Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table

Tags: azure-table-storage, asp.net-core-3.0

I have a console application that is using both the Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core library and the Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table library. There is an enum in the Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos namespace named ConsistencyLevel which is throwing errors about an ambiguous reference.

I don't know if there is a good solution to this since right now the CosmosClient for Core SQL needs to set this.

Is Microsoft planning on fixing this issue since it restricts a developer from using both libraries in the same project?
In terms of code, I have a method attempting to create a new client in the DocumentDb SDK.

```
public void Initialize(int maxConnections)
{
    this.client = new CosmosClient(this.config.Uri, this.config.AuthKey,
                                    new CosmosClientOptions()
                                    {
                                        MaxRetryAttemptsOnRateLimitedRequests = 9,
                                        MaxRetryWaitTimeOnRateLimitedRequests = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
                                        ApplicationRegion = Regions.EastUS2,
                                        ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
                                        ConsistencyLevel = ConsistencyLevel.Eventual
                                    });
    this.container = this.client.GetContainer(this.config.DatabaseName, this.config.ContainerName);
}
```

The error is:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0433  The type 'ConsistencyLevel' exists in both 'Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client, Version=3.3.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' and 'Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table, Version=1.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' DataLoader  C:\Source\Repos\poc\DataLoader\CosmosSdkv3Context.cs    69  Active
```

Comment: If you want to connect Azure Cosmos SQL API, I suggest you uninstall Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core library and the Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table library then install Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos library. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-get-started#SetupVS.